# Javascript Text Field / Date Parser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, parsing, momentjs

I am trying to a add a parser to a text field to make sure the user enters a date with the format MM/DD/YYYY. I am also using a Calendar Picker to manipulate state as well, and updating the text-box with moment.js ... however, I need to add a parser for when the user is typing the date, where they can type the / but also the / adds itself when needed.

A few scenarios with a before/after idea of parser:

```
3 -> 03/
3161995 -> 03/16/1995
31/ -> 03/01/
```

Comment: You need to be more clear on what you did, how far you are, what problems you have... share a piece of code too

Answer (score 0):

you can make use following function

```js
function formatDate(date) {
        let d = new Date(date),
            month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
            day = '' + d.getDate(),
            year = d.getFullYear();

        if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
        if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;

        return [month, day, year].join('-');
}

/* pass the data as follows  
console.log(formateDate(new Date())); */
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.